# What is the source of Herb Caen's "I have a memory like an elephant."?

Tags: quote-source

I found the following quote, attributed to author [***Herb Caen***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Caen).

> I have a memory like an elephant. I remember every elephant I've ever met.

However, my efforts to identify the source of this quote via Google has come up empty. The search results push me toward quote collections that attribute this quote to him without citation.

Interestingly, [*Wikiquote*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Herb_Caen) does not attribute this quote to him.

Is there a publication or book citation for this quote? Barring that, an interview or biographical article which provides conversational context for when he made this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is kind of hard to decipher, but this quote appears in the first paragraph of a reprinted article on the SFGate website, titled **Poor Herbert's almanac, April 22**.<sup>†</sup> At the bottom of the article, it gives the citation:

> This column originally appeared in The Chronicle on Oct. 12, 1969.

I had seen this article in my initial search, but the first paragraph read like a bunch of quips, so I thought it was just another random collection of quotes. I decided to take a deeper look at it, and discovered it seems to be the source of the original quote.

---

<sup>†</sup>[Poor Herbert's almanac, April 22](https://www.sfgate.com/entertainment/article/Poor-Herbert-s-almanac-April-22-3495845.php) by Herb Caen.